# Can I use log10(time) as an offset in a GLMM?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, glmm, glmmtmb

I'm trying to analyze a dataset but am running into a problem with one of my models. The particular set of data I'm working with is species richness data (number of species seen during each sampling period) - formatted like this:
[image]
etc

I'm using `glmmTMB` in R to investigate the effects of land use and timeframe on species richness with site as a random effect. my model looks like this:

`model.richness.1 <- glmmTMB(spec_rich ~ land_use + migration + (1|site) + offset(log(time)), data=(data), family="nbinom2")`

However, duration of sampling period is highly correlated with species richness, so I am including time as an offset. The PROBLEM is that when I include time, the model gets way overdispersed, and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried it with `Poisson` and `nbinom1` but they are even more overdispersed. I did manage to figure out that using `offset(log10(time))` fixes the overdispersion problem, BUT I'm not sure if that's acceptable to use with a GLMM and I can't seem to find anything confirming one way or the other. I just need some kind of source or something that confirms that this is an acceptable way to format the offset, or an alternative method for reducing the overdispersion in the model.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the model log-link?

Answer (score 1):

> ... duration of sampling period is highly correlated with species richness, so I am including time as an offset.

That's making a very strong, and probably incorrect, assumption about the association. A simple (log) offset in a count model makes sense in a situation like a Poisson model where the number of counts is *necessarily* proportional to spatial or temporal extent. That's probably not the case when you are counting species.

Say that there are only 3 species at your observation site. How quickly you observe each of them will depend on their numbers and observability, but you might eventually see all of them. After that, no much how longer you observe, you won't find any more. That's unlike the type of count model for which a fixed offset is useful, in which the counts will continue to increase the longer that you observe.

You evidently should model observation duration as a predictor in your model (flexibly, with a spline or other generalized additive model), but as you've found you shouldn't use it as a simple fixed offset.